# ServiceStack Is IsDebuggingEnabled in View (HttpContext missing)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack. In my layout view i need to know for an condition if the application is debugging or not. For some reason there is no HttpContext.

I've tried to install `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`. Than Install-Package `Install-Package ServiceStack.Mvc`. Now i can download localhost but there is no website visible after build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the current HttpContext via the singleton:

```
@System.Web.HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled
```